# Finding path in a matrix for sentence alignment

Tags: python, matrix, nlp, deep-learning

Following problem: I am working with python and I have two texts in different languages (texta and textb) which have both a lot of sentences. The aim is to align each sentence in texta with a sentence of textb. The overall length is roughly equal, but the number of the sentences is not. It is somewhere about 1:1.3, so at times one sentence of texta might get two sentences of textb. The order of the sentences in both texts needs to be preserved. 
Now I have a CNN that outputs a matrix of all the sentences and a propability score of them being a translation of each other. 
This might in a simplified way look like this:

```
[0.5,0.2,.0.0]
[0.1,0.6,0.4]
[0.2,0.3,0.8]
```

The accuracy of these predictions is about 50%. So when I just select the best result of each row I get a precision of 50%. 
Now one would expect the ideal path to be more or less diagonal, since both texts will contain more or less the same information at the same place. However in reality this is not always the case. A sentence can be short, a sentence can be long, sometimes a paragraph is missing (translation mistake). So I wonder what is a nice approach to solve this problem. My first idea is to just measure the distance to the diagonal center and give a penalty that reduces the propability score as further as an element is away from that center. However this approach is weak in the case that a paragraph is missing and thus a longer sequence of sentences lies further away from the center. So I am looking for a kind of optimization technique, but I do not know where to start yet.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
You describe a problem in very general terms, but the only specific you give is a case that *isn't* what you're trying to solve.  The result is not defined enough, far too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to apply a divide and conquer strategy.

As you point out, you cannot be certain of measuring through distance due to omitted paragraphs. So this breaks your proximity checks.

Since you already have a matrix for probabilities, I would try to pin those sentences that are an obvious match. So now you have 2 new significantly smaller problems around them. If you could then re-run your probability procedure, in the new subsections you will get a much more accurate probability, as you are not losing space to distant sentences. And you would get significantly sparser matrix that you just join. You would be changing your complete-graph matrix into a [block diagonal matrix.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices)

So you start with this

```
a b  c d  e f g h i  j k l m
n o  p q  r s t u v  w x y z
e f .8 h  i j k l m  n o p q
r s  t u  v w x y z  a b c d
a b  c d .7 f g h i  j k l m
n o  p q  r s t u v  w x y z
e f  g h  i j k l m  n o p q
r s  t u  v w x y z .9 b c d
a b  c d  e f g h i  j k l m
n o  p q  r s t u v  w x y z
e f  g h  i j k l m  n o p q
r s  t u  v w x y z  a b c d
a b  c d  e f g h i  j k l m
```

You pin the 3 high probability sentences and you get this (this is possible because you explicitly said there is strict order preservation)

```
1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
0 a 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 y  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0  0 s t u v  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0  0 j k l m  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 k l 0
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 x y 0
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 o p 0
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 b c 0
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1
```

*note: letters above are not the same as below after you recalculate.*

so you are left with submatrices on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere. Each block starts with a 1 and 0's in the first row and first column; and ends in a 1 and 0's in last row and last column.

With this, you are effectively boxing into submatrixes the missing paragraphs. This method depends heavily on the **quality of your high probability** matches.

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful! By setting a very high threshold in the first run the precision goes up to above 95% but then only few results are produced (only about 15% of all the sentences). But the distance between these sentences is not that high anymore, about 9 sentences average. And that is something where the diagonal/penalty-method will work very well I guess!

Comment: fantastic, that was a great bump.